# Please tell me why the code below is not working?

Tags: java

When i run the code everything works fine but the contents are not written to target.txt.

```
public class SrtExtractor {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Path source = Paths.get("files/loremipsum.txt");
            Path target = Paths.get("files/target.txt");
            Charset charSet = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(source, charSet);
            BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(target, charSet);
            String temp;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while((temp = reader.readLine())!=null){
                list.add(temp);
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
            {
                writer.append(list.get(i));//why this line is not working???
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try writer.flush() and writer.close()

Comment: You left `writer.close()`.

Comment: Have you bothered to step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: You have to close both the reader and writer when you're done; use the example at http://kodejava.org/how-to-write-file-using-files-newbufferedwriter/ to do this automatically/safely using the new try with resource feature.

Comment: adding writer.close() worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `BufferedWriter` class - In this case, the contents of your write are still in the Buffer. `writer.flush();` needs to be called to flush out the contents of the Buffer and write them to the underlying stream.

`flush()` is also called automatically when `close()` is called. `close()` should be called when your program is done with it's resources, in order to avoid memory leaks. Proper closing of resources can be difficult to do correctly, but Java 7 added a new [try-with-resources construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) to help programmers properly close their resources.

Here's your example rewritten to use the try-with-resources construct. This will ensure that both of your streams get properly closed, even if an exception occurs while processing the file. It's essentially the same as calling `close()` on your reader and writer, but it's safer and uses less code.

```
public class SRTExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path source = Paths.get("files/loremipsum.txt");
        Path target = Paths.get("files/target.txt");
        Charset charSet = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
        try (
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(source, charSet);
            BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(target, charSet);
        ) {
            String temp;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(temp);
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                writer.append(list.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Hadn't seen the new try that closes resources automatically before, nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    writer.append(list.get(i));
}
writer.close(); //Add this
reader.close(); //Add this
```

You haven't indicated that you were done writing to the file. Until you say `close()` the file isn't actually being written, the text is just sitting in the `BufferedWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone says, you should add `writer.close()`.

By other side, I think that the best way to write on a text file is this (it always runs for me):

```
File file = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
for(...){
  w.write(...);
}
```